# Is it possible to use select query inside alter statement in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

I have the following query which will delete the constraint as i did not know the constraint name, i am getting it from select query by specifying table name and column name.

```
ALTER TABLE <CHILD_TABLE_NAME>
DROP CONSTRAINT in (SELECT
    CONS.CONSTRAINT_NAME

FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS CONS
    LEFT JOIN USER_CONS_COLUMNS COLS ON COLS.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CONS.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    LEFT JOIN USER_CONSTRAINTS CONS_R ON CONS_R.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CONS.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
    LEFT JOIN USER_CONS_COLUMNS COLS_R ON COLS_R.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CONS.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME

WHERE CONS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'
AND COLS.COLUMN_NAME='<COLUMN_NAME>'
AND CONS.TABLE_NAME = '<CHILD_TABLE_NAME>')
```

when i am runnning above query , getting the below error in pl/sql developer

```
ORA-02250:missing or invalid constraint name
```

Comment: You'll have to do it in two steps. First find the constraint name, then drop the constraint.

Comment: This can't be done like that. You must do this with ***dynamic SQL*** ; look for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement examples.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out "Oracle Database SQL Language Reference" to see if "ALTER TABLE" command has in its syntax the ability to have a subquery in it, which it doesn't. Example --> http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001

"alter table" command, "drop_constraint_clause" example from the provided link

[image]

To sum up all, the answer is no you cannot have a subquery specified in a "alter table" command.

What you can do is do it with dynamic SQL as @J. Chomel specified.

Example :

```
BEGIN

     FOR i in (<<YOUR SELECT>>)
     LOOP
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||i.TABLE_NAME||' DROP CONSTRAINT '||i.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
     END LOOP;

END;
```